# Maximum Likelihood Estimates for two pdf's

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $y$, a label be $0$ or $1$, and $x$ be a scalar in the set $[-1,1]$ with likelihood function $p(x|y=0)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $p(x|y=1)=\dfrac{3x^2}{2}$, find the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat y$. I'm not sure how to begin to tackle this problem? Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Compute $p(x|y=1)$ and $p(x|y=0)$ for a given $x$ and see which one is larger.

Comment: Does this mean the estimate will be a piecewise function?

Comment: yes it will be piecewise

Comment: As in when x<=-sqrt(3)/3 or >=sqrt(3)/3 y=1/2, otherwise y=3x^2/2? I thought y was supposed to be a value?

Comment: No, $\hat y$ is either $0$ or $1$, depending on whether $p(x|y=0)$ or  $p(x|y=1)$ is larger. The decision boundaries $\pm \sqrt{3}/3$ are already correct, though.

Comment: How can $p(x=1|y=1) = \frac{3}{2}$? That doesn't sound like a normal probability distribution

Comment: Furthermore is $x$ a discrete random variable taking values $-1,1$? Otherwise it's not possible that $p(x|y=0) = \frac{1}{2} \ \forall x \in [-1,1]$

Comment: A **likelihood** function is not necessarily a **probability**.  Likelihood quantifies the tendency for a particular outcome relative to other outcomes.  A probability is a special type of likelihood, but a likelihood is not always a probability.

Answer (score 0):

The ML estimator maximizes the likelihood function, i.e.
$$\hat y = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } |x| < \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \\
1 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
because $p(x|y = 0) > p(x|y = 1)$ for $|x| < \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.